# Failed Stackdriver email notification for newly created cluster

Tags: cluster, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

I want to create monitoring and altering notification whenever someone creates a new k8s cluster.
Method:

1. Find methodName: `google.container.v1beta1.ClusterManager.CreateCluster`
2. Create Log metrics
3. Threshold value = 1
4. Create email notification policy

Result:

1. I could see spike high in monitoring graph
2. But, no email notification received.

What might be the issue that I am not getting an email notification?